# How do I add ">" where I want the user to input text? (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

If I have a System.out.println("what's your name"), I want the next line to say ">" so it makes it more obvious that it's the users turn to type something.

So far I've just put "\n > " at the end of my question, and it works fine, but then I'd have to do this every single time.

Answer (score 2):

Add a prompt method that returns a string

Create a `Scanner` as a field in the class

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Create a method to display a prompt and return a string from the `Scanner`. You might need to add `static`.

```
public String prompt(String message) {
    System.out.print(message + "\n>");
    return keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

Call the method

```
String name = prompt("Enter your name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the process with a *[class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)*.

```java
class UI {
    Scanner is;
    PrintStream os;

    UI(InputStream is, PrintStream os) {
        this.is = new Scanner(is);
        this.os = os;
    }

    String input(String s) {
        os.printf("%s%n> ", s);
        return is.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage.

```java
UI ui = new UI(System.in, System.out);
String s = ui.input("what's your name");
```

Output

```
what's your name
> abc
```